# 500 Error when trying to load any view besides the home/index view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, web-hosting, internal-server-error

I uploaded a Laravel website on a Namecheap server here: https://kdev.solutions/ and it works fine. I uploaded again (essentially the exact same files, except for some minor changes like setting APP_URL for the new domain) to another Bell server here: http://anomet.com/ and now I get an "Internal Server Error" (on the Bell server) whenever I try to navigate to a different page. Not sure how I could go about fixing this problem.

Server logs are empty. I'm using Laravel 5.4.15

Comment: Check laravel logs, under storage directory.

Comment: Laravel logs are empty as well.

Comment: Have you checked permisson of storage and bootstrap directories ?

Comment: Even with permission of both directories set to 777 (recursively) the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you checked your `apache/nginx` error logs? If yes, what did the logs say for your request?

Comment: The logs directory on the server only contains an "access_log" file that doesn't seem to be much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to navigate with :

http://exemple.org/index.php/test
instead of http://exemple.org/text

If it's working, active mod_rewrite in apache.

If not, it's a problem of permissions

`sudo chmod 755 -R laravel_blog` 
`chmod -R o+w laravel_blog/storage`

BTW : Sorry for my bad english, i'm french

Comment: Wow that first url pattern works, this page here for example now loads: http://anomet.com/index.php/lighting (although the images don't load). I'll have to figure out have to activate mod_rewrite now I guess..